# Perfomance Issuses on Tables With NonClustered Index

Tags: sql-server, performance

We have a table with about 100,000 record which is used frequently in our applications. We had an identity (ID) columns and had a clustered index on it and everything worked good. But for some reasons we had to use a Uniqueidentifier column as Primary key. So we add a non clustered index on it and removed the clustered index on ID column. But now, we have lots of performance degradation issuses from our customer in peak times. Is it because the table has no clustered index now?

Comment: it depends on the query you use to access data. why not make the UniqueIdentifier the primary key?

Comment: Guid column is primary key now and it has a nonclustered index

Comment: Did you explicitly make it non clustered? PK are by default clustered index.

Comment: So now you have **no clustered index** anymore?? That alone is a mess - your table is a heap now. Those aren't performant - period. Create that clustered index on the `ID` column again! (yes - you can have a clustered index on a column that is **not** the primary key)

Comment: I added the clustered index on ID column but SELECT * ... takes more longer :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that you added a primary key by no means implies you had to drop the clustered index. The two concepts are distinct. You can have an uniqueidentifier PK implemented by a non clustered index and a separate clustered index of choice (eg. the old `ID` column).

But the real question is **How did you change your application when you added the uniqueidentifier PK**? Did you also modified the application code to retrieve the records by this new PK (by the uniqueidentifier)? Did you update all joins to reference the new PK? Did you modified all foreign key cosntraints that referenced the old `ID` column? Or does the application continue to retrieve the data using the old identity `ID` column? My expectation is that you changed *both* the application and the table, and the access is now prevalent on the form of `SELECT ... FROM table WHERE pk=@uniqueidentifier`. If *only* such access occurs, then the table should perform OK even with a non-clustered uniqueidentifier primary key and no clustered index. So there must be something else at play:

- your application continues to access the table based on the old identity `ID` column
- there are joins in your query based on the old identity `ID` column
- there are foreign key constraints referencing the table on the old `ID` column

Ultimately you have a performance troubleshooting issue at hand and approach it as a performance troubleshooting problem. I have two great resources for you:the  [Waits and Queue methodology](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966413.aspx) and the [Performance Troubleshooting Flowchart](http://sqlcat.com/sqlcat/b/presentations/archive/2008/04/18/troubleshooting-sql-server-2005-2008-performance-and-scalability-flowchart.aspx)

Comment: Yes. We Modified our applications and wrote thousand lines of scripts(!) to update all other tables and relations. We didn't drop the ID column but drop the clustered index on it. It works fine when system is in normal situations but in peak time, it is really slow. Thanks alot for helpful links. I'm going to read them and ask again if the problem stays longer :)

Answer (score 1):

Hi I think you can make uniqueidentifier column as clustered index with NEWSEQUENTIALID() instead of NEWID(). As newsequentialid generates the sequential ids and for clustered index its the best.